# What is the part of speech is "the door" in the sentence below?

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech

Grammatically speaking what is "the door" in the following sentence?

> To answer the door, she pulled it open.

Is it a modifier?

Comment: You're confusing category (part of speech) and function. "The door" is a noun phrase, whose function here is direct object of "answer".

Comment: @BillJ Isn't "the door" a part of speech if it's an object? It functions as the object but it also is the object, no? I'm not understanding.

Comment: You're right, but you've got the rule by the wrong end. Direct objects have to be noun phrases, and nouns are almost always noun phrases. But complex constituents like _quite a few more than I expected of the bright red antique British cars on parade_ are also noun phrases -- you wouldn't want to say that was all one noun, right? As @BillJ said, _the door_ is a noun phrase. That means it's a phrase that is used like a noun. There are also verb phrases, adjective phrases, and adverb phrases, same kind of interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

*The door* is the object of the verb *answer*. The phrase *to answer the door* is an adverbial phrase of purpose modifying the main verb or the praedicate.

Comment: So if participle phrases contain participles, and prepositional phrases contain prepositions, then adverbial phrases contain adverbs. Can you identify for us the adverb in the adverbial phrase you mention?

Comment: @JosephO.: No, that is unfortunately not the case: adverbial phrases usually don't contain adverbs. Participle and praepositional phrases are constructions named after the most typical kind of word that they must contain, but they aren't (necessarily) parts of speech. Adverbial phrases, on the other hand, are named after their function in the sentence and as such are a part of speech—not after a special kind of word they must contain. A rule of thumb is that an adverbial phrase could be replaced by some adverb without changing the construction and meaning of the rest of the sentence.

Comment: So I agree with you that the terminology is not consistent in this regard, alas.

Comment: So let me get this straight: Do you not think that "to answer" is functioning as an adverb in this sentence? Before you answer, keep in mind that 10,000 grammar webpages and the grammars on my desk all agree that infinitives in sentences function as either nouns, adjectives, or adverbs.

Comment: @JosephO.: Perhaps I was unclear; I meant the opposite of how you seem to interpret my answer. What part did you interpret as saying that the phrase *to answer the door* was **not** *"functioning like an adverb"* (your words)? My answer above says, *"the phrase* to answer the door *is an adverbial phrase"*. An adverbial phrase is by definition functioning like an adverb, even though it normally does not contain an adverb.

Comment: P.S. The down-vote on your answer is not mine: while some of the wording confuses me slightly, I think our answers mostly agree.

Answer (score -1):

"To answer the door" is an infinitive phrase that is functioning as a single part of speech, an adverb modifying the main verb in the sentence "pulled". That is why Cerberus correctly calls it an adverbial phrase. That should take precedence over the idea that "the door" is a direct object of "to answer." The reason being is that "to answer" is a verbal, and does not function as a verb in this sentence or any other; it is a "former" verb doing a different job, in this case, the job of an adverb. There is enough "verbiness" left for it to still take "door" as an object, but the whole phrase is functioning as an adverb. I've seen sentence analysis (in print...check out Michael Clay Thompson's work) that wouldn't label "to answer" as a verb and would skip labelling "the door" as a D.O. for the reason given.

Comment: "To answer" is definitely still a verb. Participles begin to blur the lines between nouns and verbs, but infinitives are still ordinary verbs in English.

Comment: @curiousdannii -- "Answer" is definitely being used as a verb.  I'm pretty sure that "to" is a preposition, however.

Comment: @HotLicks No it's the infinitive *to*, usually considered a particle rather than a preposition.

Comment: @curiousdannii - Webster's calls it a preposition, as did my 8th grade English teacher.

Comment: @curiousdannii -- Infinitives can function as nouns, adjectives, and adverbs but they never function as verbs in a sentence (though their form allows them to take an object). This is why an infinitive can never be the predicate of a sentence. To call an infinitive an "ordinary verb[s] in English" is patently false, my friend. Infinitives can never have subjects (like ordinary verbs can) because they can't inflect to reflect tense or bind to subjects (like ordinary verbs can). After you research, make it right...

Comment: @HotLicks -- No, "To answer" is definitely not being used as a verb because infinitives are never used as verbs in sentences. This takes a 5 minute web search or the cracking of any English grammar text. Here's a test: "To hunt is my favorite pastime."  Remember that a subject is a "person, place, thing, or idea" that is being or doing something. But that is the same definition as a noun! So, if you concede that "To hunt" is the subject of the sentence (which is obvious...I hope) then one is committed to identifying "To hunt" as a noun.

Comment: @JosephO. - Where did I say "to answer" is being used as a verb???

Comment: @HotLicks -- 5 comments above mine, you said " "Answer" is definitely being used as a verb. I'm pretty sure that "to" is a preposition, however." Right?

Comment: @JosephO. -- You're contradicting yourself.

Comment: @HotLicks -- Unfortunately, I'm not sure what you are talking about so I can't make any corrections, but if you now think that "answer" is being used as an adverb, why don't you just edit/delete your comment and call it a day.

Comment: @JosephO. -- I didn't say "answer" is being used as an adverb either.  "To answer" is a prepositional phrase, and that's a whole 'nother can of worms.