# "To hunt is my favorite pastime." What part of speech is "to hunt" in this sentence?

Tags: parts-of-speech, grammatical-roles, infinitive-constructions

The function of infinitives seems to be up for grabs at the last post I commented at. I either need to be schooled or my interlocutors do. May your answers bring some clarity.

These are your choices. There are eight: noun, pronoun, verb, adjective, adverb, preposition, conjunction, interjection.

Avoid answers like: subject, predicate, direct/indirect object, complement, etc. These are not parts of speech.

The last post:
[What is the part of speech is "the door" in the sentence below?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/475891/what-is-the-part-of-speech-is-the-door-in-the-sentence-below/475928#475928)

Some definitions (premises):

1.A verbal is a verb form that functions as another part of speech, i.e., nouns or modifiers (adjectives or adverbs).

2.Infinitives are a subset of verbals.

Therefore,

3.Infinitives (yes, composed of two words) function as nouns, adjectives, or adverbs.

As far as I know, these are standard definitions and noncontroversial. I'm simply asking, based on these definitions what part of speech is "to hunt" functioning as in my sentence. I don't know if people are unaware of these definitions or I am seriously missing something, but no one seems to be able to pull the trigger and simply identify an infinitive in a sentence as either a noun, adjective, or adverb though this type of analysis is everywhere on the web and in the grammars on my desk. People seem to be stuck on saying these are verbs because of their form (which is understandable) but ignoring that they are verbals, which *never* function as verbs. Others forgo parts of speech altogether and jump to sentence analysis, i.e., subject/predicate/D.O./I.O./ complements and so forth.

I believe the fact that an English infinitive technically has two words is incidental and doesn't inhibit it from being analyzed a single part of speech (German, Latin, Spanish, French all have single word infinitives). Wouldn't it be odd that in all these languages, *their* infinitives could be analyzed as a part of speech because they are single words, but because English has an additional "infinitive marker" we can't? The fact that the "to" (when combined with an infinitive) is not identified as a part of speech should be the clue that it is uniquely bound to the infinitive and that both are functioning as a single word (and please don't say "to," in this case, is a preposition ).

So I'm ready to find better web sources and burn my grammars if someone who knows grammar better than me can resolve this. Thanks to those who have already commented.

Comment: Thank you for your ques­tion. As asked, it can have no an­swer be­cause parts of speech ap­ply only to in­di­vid­ual words, not to mul­ti­word phrases like “to eat” or “to town”. In­fini­tive clauses are a nom­i­nal el­e­ment in­so­far as they can be serve as NPs to ful­fil the gram­mat­i­cal roles of sub­ject or ob­ject in­clud­ing prepo­si­tional ones as in *“for him **to give** a dog a bone”*, but that no more makes them a noun than it does a gerund clause like *“giv­ing a dog a bone”*. Clauses and phrases can­not “have” a part of speech; only sin­gle words can.

Comment: Yes. Good point. Once we are talking phrases or clauses, we slip in their "part of speech" function by saying we have an "adjectival phrase" or "adverbial clause." But what if you are simply identifying each word in the sentence and labeling it as a part of speech.  Using your gerund phrase, wouldn't you write "noun" under "giving," and if not, what would you write and why?

Comment: In *“giv­ing a dog a bone”* you have a verb tak­ing both a di­rect ob­ject (the bone) and an in­di­rect one (the dog who gets that bone). Noth­ing but verbs act like that, so it is a verb.  I’m afraid that so long as you are trapped look­ing only at  parts of speech in­stead of higher-level syn­tac­tic con­stituents such as NPs, you will unerringly lead your­self into the shadow of the val­ley of dead para­doxes whence there is no es­cape. Don’t go there, for down that path lies mad­ness. Also mad lies.

Comment: Sup­pose your sen­tence added just one word to it: *“To hunt **rats** is my fa­vorite pas­time.“* Does that change any­thing? What about two more words out in front: *“**For me** to hunt cats would get me in trou­ble with my neigh­bors.*” Any en­light­en­ment yet? :) As you see, by insisting that *to hunt* “must be” a “noun”, you have backed your­self into the para­dox that *to hunt rats* and *for me to hunt cats* “must” also “be” “nouns”. That is why this does not work. You have to call those in­fin­i­tive clauses, which are here acting as NPs so that they can be the sen­tence sub­ject.

Comment: True, except for verbals, which again are verb forms functioning as something other than verbs...by definition. Even though a gerund (which is a verbal) functions as a noun in the sentence, because it's derived from a verb it can still take direct objects. I could just as easily say, "Only nouns or pronouns function as subjects of sentences" so check out "Giving is a virtue."  Here we have another gerund. Would you identify "giving" as a verb in the sentence? Would the part of speech change if we added "money" as "Giving money is a virtue." BTW, I really appreciate this exchange.

Comment: When you say “func­tions as a noun”, you are con­fus­ing syn­tac­tic func­tions with parts of speech. The mo­ment you equate “func­tions as” with be­ing a sin­gle part of speech, you are cre­at­ing a con­fu­sion that leads to para­dox and in­cor­rect anal­y­sis. The sub­jects of these sen­tences con­tain no nouns: *“It died. What I told you is true. For her to call me is im­pos­si­ble now. Giv­ing me them won’t get you in trou­ble.”* Let’s wait for the real syn­tac­ti­cians like Law­ler to see your ques­tion.

Comment: Amazing. I didn't see your post until I posted mine, but it seems we are thinking along the same lines. I'm not saying I wouldn't call them infinitive clauses...I would...if I was identifying clauses. The whole clause is acting like a noun, that is why we call it a NP. But at the level of parts of speech: "for me to hunt cats" is for=prep., me=pron., to hunt= noun, cats=noun. Let me make it clear, I think your phrase and clause analysis is spot on. When I learned grammar we did a four level analysis, parts of speech, parts of the sentence, phrases, clauses and never did we cross them.

Comment: In “to hunt cats”, that *to hunt* can­not be a noun be­cause it has an ob­ject. The re­la­tion­ship be­tween those words makes no sense oth­er­wise. In *“The hunt­ing **of** cats is il­le­gal here”*, that has two nouns though, con­nected by a prepo­si­tion. You should prob­a­bly visit our chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87659/discussion-between-joseph-o-and-tchrist).

Answer (score 1):

Having read the other post referred to, along with its comments, it seems that there are different schools involved here... Personally, I'd say that *to hunt* is not a part of speech in the first place – it's an infinitive clause, consisting of two formal parts: an infinitive marker (*to*) and a verb (*hunt*). So, an approximate answer here would be that the part of speech of *hunt* (without the infinitive marker) is a verb.

However, judging from the comments to the other post you're referring to, there seems to be another school, which seems to use the term *part of speech* in a different sense, *viz* meaning 'clause element', i.e. referring to the function in the clause. With this interpretation *to hunt* would obviously be a subject though, so it's difficult to give a straight answer to the original question even with this interpretation, seeing that "subject" is not allowed as an answer...

So, Joseph O, do you have a third take on this, seeing that you seem to have the same view as me when it comes to what constitutes a part of speech (judging from your examples – noun, verb...), but still ask about a constituent that is (in its entirety) clearly NOT a part of speech in this view? What reference works do you adhere to?

Comment: Your first instincts are correct: one can only assign a part of speech to a single word, not to multiple words taken together as a syntactic constituent. The asker may be confused about grammatical roles versus parts of speech; if so, this is a common confusion.

Comment: @tchrist yeah, but then the asker also distinctly says that functions are NOT parts of speech, so it seems to be more complicated than that...

Comment: Then I don’t understand what he’s asking. I’ve asked the asker to clarify his question.

Comment: @Hannah Thanks for your answer. But where did I say "functions are NOT parts of speech"?

Comment: @Hannah Also, to your above question, I was taught that every word in every sentence can be categorized within the eight parts of speech. I don't know if that is standard practice and I would be very interested to know which words don't fit within those categories and why.

Comment: @JosephO. You say "Avoid answers like: subject, predicate, direct/indirect object, complement, etc. These are not parts of speech." right? This would be the same as saying "functions are not parts of speech", since subject etc are functions (whereas parts of speech such as noun, verb etc are FORMS/CATEGORIES). See? As for your second comment, not all words can be classified as a part of speech, no – nor is there a single fixed set of parts of speech, unfortunately; different grammars propose slightly different sets...

Comment: @JosephO. Also, I'd still very much like to know what reference works you're using – "the grammars on my desk" that you are referring to – because they seem to mix things in a whole different way than I myself am used to :)

Answer (score 0):

It is the Infinitive, which is one of the infinite verb forms, or verbals / like Gerund and Participles/.
In the sentence 'To hunt' is used as the Subject of the sentence.
According to Wiktionary: the Infinitive is used to express a thing in a general manner.
This meaning is traced back to the Old English language / and to the Proto-Germanic language/ when the Infinitive was declinable, which proves its nominal origin.